# How i fix this error? helpme .. Incorrect syntax near '@harga_jual'.'

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, azure-sql-database, importerror

```vb
Sub import2DB()
    Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=172.16.250.3;Initial Catalog=KIAS;User ID=sa;Password=p4yr0ll;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("insert into Pr_masterItem
        (item_id, item_name, inventory, subtitutes_exist, assembly_bom, satuan, cost_is_adjusted, harga_beli, harga_jual) values
        (@item_id, @item_name, @inventory, @subtitutes_exist, @assembly_bom, @satuan, @cost_is_adjusted, @harga_beli, @harga_jual", conn2)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("item_id", row.Cells("item_id").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("item_name", row.Cells("item_name").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("inventory", row.Cells("inventory").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("subtitutes_exist", row.Cells("subtitutes_exist").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("assembly_bom", row.Cells("assembly_bom").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("satuan", row.Cells("satuan").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("cost_is_adjusted", row.Cells("cost_is_adjusted").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("harga_beli", row.Cells("harga_beli").Value.ToString)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("harga_jual", row.Cells("harga_jual").Value.ToString)
        conn2.Open()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn2.Close()
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Import Berhasil")
End Sub
```

this code should can importing the data excel to sql server in vb net

EDIT:

```sql
insert into Pr_masterItem
(
    item_id,
    item_name,
    inventory,
    subtitutes_exist,
    assembly_bom,
    satuan,
    cost_is_adjusted,
    harga_beli,
    harga_jual
)
values
(
    @item_id,
    @item_name,
    @inventory,
    @subtitutes_exist,
    @assembly_bom,
    @satuan,
    @cost_is_adjusted,
    @harga_beli,
    @harga_jual
```

Comment: This is an issue that you should have been able to solve for yourself just by looking at the relevant code. The syntax error is, as the error message telling you, in your SQL code, so none of that VB code is relevant. Look at your SQL code properly. Copy it and paste it into SSMS if necessary and look at it properly. If you know what the format of an `INSERT` statement should be, it should be obvious what's wrong with yours.

Comment: Please don't post unformatted code snippets., They are all but unreadable. I have formatted this one for you. Please do so for us in future.

Comment: I've edited your question and added a formatted version of your SQL code. That should make the issue obvious and also make it obvious how you can and should be at least trying to solve such issues for yourself.

Comment: 1) Where the parameters are being added, you need to put the "@" in front of their names. 2) Although it probably makes no difference in this case as only strings are being passed, you should be aware of [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your INSERT statement is not complete. Please see [INSERT syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql):

```
INSERT INTO <object> ( column_list ) VALUES ( expression, ...n )
```

Your INSERT statement doesn't have a closing parenthesis:

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("insert into Pr_masterItem
        (item_id, item_name, inventory, subtitutes_exist, assembly_bom, satuan, cost_is_adjusted, harga_beli, harga_jual) values
        (@item_id, @item_name, @inventory, @subtitutes_exist, @assembly_bom, @satuan, @cost_is_adjusted, @harga_beli, @harga_jual", conn2)
```

You need to end your list with ')':

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("insert into Pr_masterItem
        (item_id, item_name, inventory, subtitutes_exist, assembly_bom, satuan, cost_is_adjusted, harga_beli, harga_jual) values
        (@item_id, @item_name, @inventory, @subtitutes_exist, @assembly_bom, @satuan, @cost_is_adjusted, @harga_beli, @harga_jual)", conn2)
```